# error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]|

Tags: c++, c

just a noob trying a programm
i am facing the error and i dont knpw how to resolve it
i wanted the functionto retuen one string that could be used for further use in main

```
char word_inventory(int ran)
{
    char cities[][12]={
        "ambala",
        "yamunanagar",
        "delhi",
        "gurgaon",
        "jaipur",
        "chandigarh",
        "pune",
        "mumbai",
        "dehradun",
        "rajpura"
        };
    return cities[ran];

}
int main()
{    int win=0;
     cout<<"welcome to hangman"<<endl;
    cout<<"guess the city"<<endl;
    randum = rand() % 10 + 0;
    strcpy(word,word_inventory(randum)); //here is the error
    x=strlen(word);
```

Comment: First of all, `word_inventory()` returns a single `char`, but you probably want it to return a whole word, i.e. a pointer to char(s).  This is also why you compiler is complaining: `strcopy` takes two arguments, the first of type `char*` and the second of type `const char*`, but you only pass it a single `char` (without the `*`), which cannot be automatically converted to a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate error is that `cities[ran]` is an array of chars, which does not match your function's return type. The array would decay to a pointer to the first element, so you could return `char *`.

The bigger problem is that the pointer wouldn't be valid, because the lifetime of array into which it points ends at the end of the function call. One solution is to make the array `static`, so it has permanent lifetime.